# vue3 filtered data on computed with chartjs

Tags: chart.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

im learning about vuejs 3 and for example i want to show a chartjs with a combo to filter data. (Without the combo, everything works correctly)

i have a parent component **chartjs.vue** where import the chartjs and the combo. when i select a year, i change the variable and show it on the template

```
<script setup>
import ChartJsBarChart from '@/views/charts/chartjs/ChartJsBarChart.vue'
import SelectYear from '@/componentes/selectYear.vue'


const api = ref('exp')
const year = ref([])

function selectYear(x) {
  year.value = x
}
</script>

<template>
  

    <!--  Latest Statistics -->
    <VCol cols="24" md="12">
      <VCard>
        <VCardItem class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-space-between gap-4">
          <VCardTitle>Choose a year</VCardTitle>          
        </VCardItem>

        <VCardText>
          <SelectAno @input="selectAYear" />
        </VCardText>
      </VCard>
    </VCol>

    <VCol cols="24" md="12">
      <VCard>
        <VCardItem class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-space-between gap-4">
          <VCardTitle>Total</VCardTitle>
        </VCardItem>

        <VCardText>
          <ChartJsBarChart :yearSelected="year" :url="api" />
        </VCardText>
      </VCard>
    </VCol>

</template>
```

one child component with a select (to try props and emit) **selectYear.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { ref, defineEmits, watch } from 'vue'

const emit = defineEmits(['input'])
let selected = ref([])

const years = [
  '2005',
  '2008',
  '2009',
  '2010',
  '2011',
  '2012',
  '2014',
  '2015',
  '2016',
  '2017',
  '2018',
  '2019',
  '2020',
  '2021',
  '2022',
  '2023',
]

watch(
  () => selected.value,
  (newValue, oldValue) => {
    change(newValue)
  },
)

const change = val => emit('input', val)
</script>

<template>
  <VSelect
    v-model="selected"
    :items="years"    
    label="choose a year"    
  />
</template>
```

and last child component with the chartjs ChartJsBarChart.vue

```
<script setup>
import BarChart from '@/libs/chartjs/components/BarChart'
import axios from '@axios'
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from "vue"
import { useStatesStore } from '@/store/states'

const props = defineProps({
  url: {
    type: null,
    required: true,
  },
  yearSelected: {
    type: null,
    required: true,
  },
})

const apiData = ref([]) //data from API
const data = ref({}) // data parsed to chartjs
const store = useStatesStore()
const states = ref(store.states) // legend

const filterByYear = computed(() => {
  return apiData.value.filter(item => item.year === '2005')
})

onMounted(async () => {
  await axios
    .get('/api/dashboard/expProvActiv')
    .then(res => {
      apiData.value = res.data['hydra:member']      
    })
})
</script>

<template>
  {{ props.yearSelected }}
  <hr>
  {{ apiData }}
  <BarChart
    :height="400"
    :chart-data="data"
  />
</template>
```

the result (shortened) of {{ apiData }} with hundred of items is:

```
[ { "state": "state 1", "activity": "string", "subactivity": "string", "year": 2015, "surface": "3.5500", "total": 3, "rcs": 3 }, { "state": "state 2", "activity": "string", "subactivity": "string", "year": 2016, "surface": "10.9400", "total": 13, "rcs": 13 }]
```

if i try to show filterByYear, the first time i have not data and how can i do to call filterByYear when i change the year?

**[answer myself]** the year was string instead number

how can i update the child component BarChart to update the information?

thank you!

Comment: If you want to filter the values by the year selected, then it should "item.year === yearSelected" and not "item.year === '2005'"

Comment: yes. my text was a test to try to filter something. the "real" code is "item.year === yearSelected" but i have no data.

Comment: mmm...i made a mistake...with 2005 instead of '2005' its goes right so my problem is 'year' is not a number. Its a string :(

Comment: You can coerce both sides of the equality operator to Number - e.g. `+item.year === +yearSelected`